# VB.Net equivalent of Matlab's colon operator

Tags: vb.net

Is there a function in VB.NET which generates a 1D array of numbers given the start value, end value and step, similar to Matlab's [colon operator](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html#bvg1wnp-i)

If not, could someone suggest an efficient way to write one like

`getColoumnVector(startVal As Double, step As Double, endVal As Double) As Double ()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the colon operator shows how to do it:

> The vector elements are roughly equal to [j,j+i,j+2*i,...,j+m*i] where m = fix((k-j)/i). However, if i is not an integer, then floating point arithmetic plays a role in determining whether colon includes the endpoint k in the vector, since k might not be exactly equal to j+m*i

So:

```
Function GetColumnVector(startVal As Double, [step] As Double, endVal As Double) As Double()
    Dim nValues = CInt(Math.Ceiling((endVal - startVal) / [step])) + 1
    Dim result(nValues - 1) As Double

    For i = 0 To nValues - 1
        result(i) = startVal + i * [step]
    Next

    Return result

End Function
```

And there's no need to convert from a list to an array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work better and as expected

```
    Public Function GetColumnVector(startVal As Double, [step] As Double, endVal As Double) As Double()
    Dim list As New List(Of Double)
    For d = startVal To endVal Step [step]
        list.Add(d)
    Next
    Return list.Concat({endVal}).ToArray()
```